# Getting list of middle values in between values of list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a list of values: `[0,2,3,5,6,7,9]` and want to get a list of the numbers in the middle in between each number: `[1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 6.5, 8]`. Is there a neat way in python to do that?

Comment: you can use steps in array `a[::2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple list comprehension (note I'm asuming you want all your values as `float`s rather than a mixture of `int`s and `float`s):

```
>>> lst = [0,2,3,5,6,7,9] 
>>> [(a + b) / 2.0 for a,b in zip(lst, lst[1:])]
[1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 5.5, 6.5, 8.0]
```

(Dividing by `2.0` ensure floor division is not applied in Python 2)

Answer (score 3):

Use a for loop:

```
>>> a = [0,2,3,5,6,7,9]
>>> [(a[x] + a[x + 1])/2 for x in range(len(a)-1)]
[1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 5.5, 6.5, 8.0]
```

However using zip as @Chris_Rands said is better... (and more readable ¬¬)

Answer (score 1):

```
values = [0,2,3,5,6,7,9] 
middle_values = [(values[i] + values[i + 1]) / 2.0 for i in range(len(values) - 1)]
```

Dividing by `2.0` rather than `2` is unnecessary in Python 3, or if you use `from __future__ import division` to change the integer division behavior.

The `zip` or `itertools.izip` answers are more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) solution:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> values = [0,2,3,5,6,7,9]
>>> [(a+b)/2.0 for a,b in itertools.izip(values, itertools.islice(values, 1, None))]
[1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 5.5, 6.5, 8.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`[(l[i]+l[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(l)-1)]`

Answer (score 0):

Simple for loop:

```
nums = [0,2,3,5,6,7,9]
betweens = []
for i in range(1, len(nums)):
    if nums[i] - nums[i-1] > 1:
        betweens.extend([item for item in range(nums[i-1]+1, nums[i])])
    else:
        betweens.append((nums[i] + nums[i-1]) / 2)
```

Output is as desired, which doesn't need further conversion (in Python3.x):

```
[1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 6.5, 8]
```

Comment: What is that `extend` branch of the conditional trying to do?

Comment: Umm, what's `if nums[i] - nums[i-1] > 1:` and `betweens.extend(item for item in range(nums[i-1], nums[i])` for? Nowhere in the question has the OP said that numbers with a difference of more than 1 should be treated differently.

Comment: @Rawing To handle multiple numbers in between.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. Your code produces `[0, 1, 2.5, 3, 4, 5.5, 6.5, 7, 8]` instead of the expected `[1, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 6.5, 8]`.

Comment: @Rawing Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited it and now it's correct.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Including multiple in-between numbers.

Comment: The question doesn't specify what should be done on a gap of more than 2, but it sure looks to me like the OP wants the medians of successive values - eg `[8, 12]` should become `[10]` rather than `[9, 10, 11]`. The `[1, 3]` -> `[2.5]` example indicates that, at least to me.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I can't find that example.

Comment: It's the 2nd and 3rd pair of values in the OP's sample input list.